# Python pandas keeps printing row numbers inside my columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Never used pandas before and I can't find any answers for why pandas keeps adding row numbers into my output. My code:

```
df = pandas.read_excel(file, usecols=[2], header=1)
print(df)
with open("blah.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(df))
```

And the output is:

```
   test
0  car
1  plane
```

Rather I would like it to be a simple as it is in the excel file and only column data in txt format:

```
test
car
plane
```

Comment: df.columns should return a list of headers and df['test'] should print the column.  showindex=False should remove the index.

Comment: Hi @arundeepchohan I removed the headers using `header=1`, I also tried using `showindex=False` but every time I do I get error: `TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'showindex'`

Comment: Must have been index then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
with open("blah.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(df))
```

With this:

```
df.to_csv("blah.txt", index=False)
```

If you want to control more aspects of the output: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html